Data label for Radio buttons not being set in apex toolkit
I have to add visibility conditions on a few text fields based on the selection of radio button. For that I need to give the data label of the radio button and selected value in the withCondition method of text fields. I have tried many things but unable to set data label for a radio button and hence unable to put conditional text fields based on the radio buttons.
Below is my Radio button creation apex code:
public static dfsle.RadioGroupTab.Radio radioTab1 = new dfsle.RadioGroupTab.Radio(1, new dfsle.RadioGroupTab.Position(0,
                                                    200, // The width of the tab in pixels
                                                    300), null,
                                                    new dfsle.Tab.Anchor('{radio1}', // Anchor string
                                            false, // Do not allow white space in anchor string
                                            false, // Anchor string is not case sensitive
                                            'left', // Horizontal alignment in relation to the anchor text
                                            true, // Ignore if the anchor text is not present in the document
                                            true, // Must match the value of the anchor string in its entirety
                                            'pixels', // Unit of the x and y offset properties
                                            5, // X offset
                                            0) // Y offset
                                            ,'Yes', false, false, true);


Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  If this is for the Docusign Apex Toolkit, have you contacted Docusign support?
